# How to use the range (..) operator to find lines from "String" to "\n\n"?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add a block of text to an output file, using:

```
File.foreach("#{options[:source]}") do |li|
    if (li['Exception:'] .. li["\n\n"]) then
            bufferBlocks.push(li)
    end
end
```

An example exception could be:

```
#^^ log continues prior to this ^^
words .. words .. words
words .. words .. words

words .. words .. words
words .. words .. words

Exception: ERROR 50001
File:  source.cpp
Line:  221
Msg: Encountered unknown server error!

words .. words .. words
words .. words .. words

words .. words .. words
#\/  log continues below this \/
```

And all I'd want in my output is the block:

```
Exception: ERROR 50001
File:  source.cpp
Line:  221
Msg: Encountered unknown server error!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to do.  It is important to remember that every "li" will just be a single line and end with a "\n", so you have to look for "\n" instead of "\n\n".  I have not tried it but this should work:

```
File.foreach(filename) do |li|
    if (li.start_with? "Exception:") ... (li == "\n")
        bufferBlocks.push(li)
    end
end
```

I can't find any good documentation on it, but I suppose it is called a flip-flop (thanks bjhaid).  If Ruby sees a range literal being used inside that part of an "if", then it will treat it very specially.  The first part of the range just has to be a bit of code that returns true when you want the condition (flip flop) to start being true.  Similarly, the second part of the range tells Ruby when the condition should stop being true.

By the way, you could accomplish the same thing with a simple local variable:

```
in_exception = false
File.foreach(filename) do |li|
    if in_exception
        in_exception = !(li == "\n")
    else
        in_exception = (li.start_with? "Exception:")
    end

    if in_exception
        bufferBlocks.push(li)
    end
end
```

Comment: its called flip-flop in ruby and scanning log files is one the few places you would use a flip-flop in ruby

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `li` is the string containing input, you can do this:

```
li.scan(/Exception: .*?\nFile: .*?\nLine: .*?\nMsg: .*?$/m)
```

which returns an array of all the occurences. In your example:

```
["Exception: ERROR 50001\nFile:  source.cpp\nLine:  221\nMsg: Encountered unknown server error!"]
```

Comment: I've updated my post to be more accurate - there are multiple instances of "\n\n" throughout the log.